# Move coordinate system in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

The coordinate system in viewport3D in wpf is fixed at the center of the screen with positive X-axis being rightward, positive Y-axis upwards and Z-axis pointing outwards. All the calculations in transform are being made with respect to this transform. My question is, how can I change the position and orientation of this coordinate system in my code dynamically. 
The requirement is, I have two wheels rolling on the ground. But when the wheels take a 90 degree turn, the axes get interchanged. So, If I could shift and orient this coordinate system, I can tackle this problem.